# How can I calculate the total price using two different collections in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Good day, I am still new to Firebase/Firestore. I am creating a laundry app and I would like the user to choose a laundry service based on price per basket.

After the user has selected all items and set quantities per item example

I want to get a quotation from all laundry services and display to user in a recyclerview from cheapest to most expensive.

Each laundry Service should have its own price for the same Items. It would have been easier had they all agreed upon the same prices.

I need to get the first item from the order list and quantity go to business collection and find the same item based on id then return the price. After that, I will multiply the price by quantity for the first item and do that for the remaining items in the basket to get a total price.

I will then display that total price on the first CardView in my recycerview.

Then repeat the process for the second CardView etc...

Here is my Database Structure

[database root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEI3U.png)

[order list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLanL.png)

[laundry serices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaDr8.png)

Here is my sample code

```java
    orderRef.document(orderId).collection("orderlist").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                        if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {


                                String itemId = queryDocumentSnapshot.getId();
                                double quantity = queryDocumentSnapshot.getDouble("quantity");

                                businessItemPriceRef.document(businessId).collection("product_prices_list").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                                    double total = 0;

                                                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot query : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {

                                                        String businessItemPriceID = query.getId();

                                                        double item_price = query.getDouble("price_unit");

                                                        if(itemId.equals(businessItemPriceID)) {

                                                            if (item_price > 0.0) {

                                                                double item_price_quantity = item_price * quantity;
                                                                total += item_price_quantity;
                                                                //holder.setCost(total);
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

                            }

                            // Get the complete Price here

                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you need to get.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have updated my question hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Well, this code does not add up the total price as I want. instead the I am getting the price of the last item in the iteration